# How to start all microservices by one command in nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, microservices

I have a project with 5 microservices on nestjs and it takes a very long time to run each one manually. I have a main microservice, when I start it, I want the rest of the microservices to start. How should I do it? If there are similar options, please suggest

Comment: Your OS is Linux?

Comment: Windows, but if there is an idea, I'm interested to hear it

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not an official way to do it. I use this library [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently). Then you can do something like:

```
concurrently "yarn run start:api-gateway:dev" "yarn run start:identity:dev"
```

And you will see all logs in the same terminal window.